# Why does the form_for method take a symbol as its argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on the Rails blog tutorial and the syntax goes:

```
<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
```

I don't really understand when a helper method or a method takes a symbol as an argument and when it doesn't...

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: You can use `:article` in the #new view: no previous record of :article exists, you are creating a new article so you just need to tell rails this is a form for an article you are doing. In the edit view, you can use `@article` instead of `:article`, then the form will pick up the already known values for the very article you want to modify (and then prefill your form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

form_for accepts multiple types of arguments.

(a) symbol: form_for :article

```
  form elements can accessed in controller by params[:article]
```

(b) string: form_for "article"

```
  form elements can be accessed in controller by params[:article]
```

(c) object: form_for @article

```
  (1) Here @article is expected to contain an instance of Article. In the controller this form elements can be accessed through params[:article].

  (2) If a form is expected to be accessed through a custom name, it can be done by using :as operator. form_for @post, as: :my_post
```

(d) array: form_for [:my, @article]

```
   :my is used to namespace @article. With params[:my_article] form elements can be accessed in controller
```

Answer (score 0):

Some additional details are needed to understand the answer: This function actually takes a symbol, string or path as the possible argument.

To answer the question of "why": Symbol is used by default because the comparison is faster than a direct string comparison.

Comment: I am not certain this is an actual *"Answer"*. Seems more fitting as a comment